# Multiple PHP installs with separate PEAR

Tags: php, installation, pear

I have two PHP installations PHP 5.2.17 and PHP 5.3.8 and I am wondering how I would go about installing a separate PEAR installation for each version of PHP?

This is on windows and IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use separate PEAR configuration files that you can specify with `pear -C /path/to/config/file` - one for each installation.

Comment: Is this done while running go-pear.bat or can this been changed afterwards?

Comment: You can do that from an existing pear installation. Use pear config-create, then pear -C /path/to/config install pear.